# How to paint my simple 2D game world, in console , smoothly?

Tags: cmd, paint, smoothing, 2d-games

I want to render my 2D semi_text-based game scene, in the console (cmd) as my frame output ...

I did it by **printing a 2D-array** of simple character that present my game world. ( like "-" and "|" )

but each frame ( = each loop ) I want to clear screen to repaint my matrix .
and now I use system("cls") ... But It's too slow !
Here is my render function :

```
void Engine::engineRender()
{    
    system("cls");          
    // Render Background        
    for(int i=0; i<10 ; i++ )
    {       
        for ( int j=0 ; j<40 ; j++ )
        {           
            printf("%c",map[i][j]);             
            if((int)(player1->yPos)==i && (int)(player1->xPos)==j )
                printf("\b&");          

        }           
        printf("\n");           
    }
}
```

And my Main Game loop is this :

```
 while(true)
    {
        _ftime(&cur);
        elapsMili += (cur.time - last.time)*1000 + (cur.millitm - last.millitm) ;

        if ( elapsMili >= 1000/frameRate ){
            elapsMili -= 1000/frameRate ;
            last=cur;
            needRender = true ;
        }
        engineUpdate();
        if (needRender){
            engineRender();
            needRender=false;
        }
    }
```

any idea to have more smooth render ?

Comment: You should paste your code to get better help

Comment: Maybe try not to clear the screen each time, but to update those characters that changed after drawing the previous frame and should be drawn differently in the current one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [a little library](https://github.com/hobwekiva/wincongfx) I made just for this purpose (fast smooth console rendering). It should be pretty straightforward to use. It works only on windows though.

Comment: Sorry but this is a little late for me and I just took a look at your code. good work ! Hope your code works for other people ;)